# specific file for leverage browser caching

Tags: .htaccess, x-cart

I have added below code in htaccess

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

But still I am getting some files to add for leverage browser caching.

Can I add specific files in .htaccess for leverage browser caching?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html

Apache Module mod_expires supports 3 directives

- ExpiresActive
- ExpiresByType
- ExpiresDefault

The syntax of the **ExpiresByType** directive is

```
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html#expiresbytype
ExpiresByType MIME-type <code>seconds
```

or

```
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html#AltSyn  
ExpiresByType type/encoding "base[plus num type] [num type] ..."
```